# Use of Facebook "user_photos" permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fraud-prevention

We are currently working on a project which aims to **minimize fraud in our e-commerce platform**. In particular we seek to avoid fraud of users with **multiple accounts** (same human behind those accounts).

To address this problem we are designing a mechanism intended to **verify the identity** of users who have multiple accounts. **This mechanism will apply only to users with risky behavior within our platform.**

The mechanism consists on asking the user to connect with his Facebook account and grant certain permissions to our application, which allow us to verify the veracity of his account.

We will require the following:

- That his account has more than 50 friends.
- That his account has activity over 6 months ago.
- **That the user can correctly identify the face of 5 friends. (similar to Facebook Social Captcha)**

To achieve this our Facebook application needs the following permissions:

- user_friends
- email
- **user_photos (requires review of the application)**

We do not want to start developing this mechanism without being sure that Facebook will approve “user_photos” permission.

So, our questions are:

- Is it possible to use the information in this way?
- Are we going against Facebook policies by doing this?
- Is there any way to ensure that Facebook will approve those permissions to our application before starting development?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can only access those friends which also use your application. It's no longer possible to get all friends since the introduction of the Graph API v2.0. Why you'd need the `user_photos` permission. You can request the profile picture of a user's friends without this permission:

```
GET /me?fields=id,name,friends{id,name,picture}
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

> The `/me/friends` endpoint no longer includes the full list of a person's friends. Instead, it now returns the list of that person's friends who are also using your app.

Comment: Only friends who use the application is not enough for us.

With the permission "user_friends" we can not get the complete list of friends, but the api provides the total count in the "summary" field, with this is enough.

We need "user_photos" permission to get user photos (tagged or uploaded) and the tags with the names and ids of his friends. This info is provided by Graph, you can check it here: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fphotos%3Ffields%3Dsource%2Ctags&).

Comment: I don't really understand how this should work with your given use case

Answer (score 0):

You can view the actual platform policy here. I don't think there is a policy against it but the design won't allow you to implement it.

https://developers.facebook.com/policy

The fields that you can actually query are visible here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

As you can see the account creation time is not available to be queried. Hope this helps.

Finally, Facebook does make an effort to remove fake accounts so connecting your Facebook account it is a signal of the user being real.